# Trying to replace a kitchen faucet

Tags: faucet

I'm trying to replace a kitchen faucet. The stud and nut holding the faucet down are both turning. I'm out of ideas.[image]

Comment: what bolt and nut?

Comment: I don't see a nut or bolt in your picture. Oh wait ......

Comment: It's an older faucet with regular nits holding it in place. Unlike the newer models which have the large plastic nuts.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. a picture, model, just what's happening) before we can help you.

Comment: try cutting a slot in the end of the bolt and then use a standard blade screwdriver to turn it ......... or you could drill a hole in the bolt and then screw in a thinner bolt .... tightening the thinner bolt would make the bigger bolt turn

Comment: Sometimes the only way I could remove an old faucet is just with a grinder, cutting the faucet into pieces..

Answer (score 1):

WD-40, A box wrench and a pair of pliers. Apply WD-40. Get the wrench on the nut and gently hold the bolt down as low as it can go. Turn your wrench while holding the bolt. Hold the bolt with the pliers harder until it frees up. Be careful to not marre the threads because you will have to bring the nut down through the damaged section if damage occurs.

A better way is to cut a slot in the bolt with a cut off disk on a grinder and use a slotted screw driver to hold the bolt in place. This method is potentially dangerous and not recommended if you are not comfortable and experienced with a grinder.

Answer (score 0):

What you show is a stud coming through a plate washer with a nut.

If you continue undoing the nut then the stud should come out of the faucet body but it may be in a long way.

If the thread is damaged inside the faucet and it is just rotating then you may be in for the long haul with a hacksaw or drilling the nut until it can be split.